# Symfony 4 - Creation form - Object is null

Tags: symfony, symfony4

- Symfony 4.3
- Custom users provider (no FOS)
- PHP 7.1 / MariaDB 10.2
- Wamp local server

I already made users edit and users delete functions. It work PERFECT !
Now I want to create a registration form in my website but I don't understand the error !

> Return value of App\Entity\User::getFirstname() must be of the type string, null returned

The exception :

> in \src/Entity/User.php (line 100)

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string")
* @Assert\NotBlank()
*/
private $firstname;

public function getFirstname(): string
{
  return $this->firstname; // THIS IS LINE 100
}
```

Below is an extract from my UserController :

```
/**
* @Route("/users/add", name="app_users_add")
*/
public function addUser(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em): Response
{
  $user = new User();
  $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user); // This line generates the error

  [...]

  return $this->render('user/add.html.twig', [
    'form' => $form->createView()
  ]);
}
```

I really don't understand.

- My `UserEntity` is working with my edit method in controller.
- MY template `user/add.html.twig` is good (even if I let it empty)
- My `UserType` form builder work well (I use the same for editing users)

Comment: can you show your registration form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add

```
public function getFirstname(): ?string
    return $this->firstname;  
}
```

Comment: It works ! By the way, I had to do the same for all the entity getters.

Comment: The php documentation explain why the `?` is solving the probleme :[Returning values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php)

The `?` allow the returned value to be null.

Answer (score 0):

The reason `$form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);` generates an error is because you are passing `$user` as data to the form `UserType`. (this is refering to a file `App\Form\UserType`, right?). Since `$user` is a new object, `$firstname` of this user is not yet defined, thus the error occurs when you are passing the data of `$user` to the form. Simply removing the `$user` argument will work.

If you do not have a file `App\Form\UserType`, you can either create it or use `createFormBuilder()` in your controller. See the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html) for more information.

Comment: If I follow your advice, the same error occurs when I submit the form.